Angular momentum of matter halos?
How much momentum (or more specifically, angular momentum) could a matter halo (like a dark matter halo, a neutrino halo...) have? Is it possible that they may have high amounts of momentum?
For instance, neutrinos (or other dark matter) directions in a halo would be expected to be fairly randomised (The neutrinos in the halo arrive from all directions over time). Also, cold neutrinos don't have much momentum.
However, if we had a fairly large halo, with a lot of matter, following the momentum formula
L = Iω = mvR
Wouldn't a high amount of mass translate into a high amount of angular momentum?

If you're curious what people find in simulations, the standard term is halo spin.

A system with high angular momentum tends to spread out. If you want to have a stable system with high angular momentum, there needs to be some inwards force keeping it together. For example, accretion disks around black holes can have huge angular momentum because the attraction is so strong.

The formula $L = mvR$ only applies to to a point mass $m$ rotating around some axis with radius $R$ with velocity $v$. In dark matter halos, you have a lot of particles moving in random directions, so a lot of the angular momentum is going to get cancelled out. The total amount of angular momentum varies among different halos. We know that, because the angular momentum affects the shape of the halo. For example, if $L$ is large around the $z$ axis, particles in the $x-y$ plane will be pushed out due to the centrifugal force, thus turning the shape into a oblate spheroid.
The amount of angular momentum that a halo can have still depends on its mass, because the centrifugal force of a particle rotating aroung the center has to be balanced out by the gravitational force of the total mass enclosed in its orbit. Consider, for simplicity, a particle of mass $m$ which orbits in a perfect circle of radius $R$ from the center with velocity $v$. Then the centrifugal force pushing it outward is
$$m \frac{v^2}{R}$$
The gravitational force pulling it inward is
$$\frac{G M m}{R^2}$$
where $M$ is the total mass enclosed in $R$. If we want the system to be stable, the forces have to balance out:
$$m\frac{v^2}{R} = \frac{GMm}{R^2}$$
$$v = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{R}}$$
So the typical orbital velocity is proportional to the square of the halo mass. But again, the particles typically don't orbit in perfect circles arount a single axis. Particles which orbit in near-perfect circles around the center are called rotation dominated. These particles contribute to the total angular momentum of the system. Particles with randomized velocities are called dispersion dominated. These particles don't contribute to the total angular momentum because their angular momenta cancel out.
Thus, the total angular momentum of the halo depends on the ratio of rotation dominated to dispersion dominated particles (which varies from halo to halo) aswell as the total mass.

so it's possible that these halos may have a large L? Is it completely unrelated to the amount of mass that they have then? @LenardKasselmann

@vengaq I updated the answer to adress the second part of your question. Regarding the first part: It depends on what you mean by large. If you are looking for the actual numbers I don't know them off the top of my head, but I'm sure there are many papers on this.

Thank you. And is it more likely that the halo contains more rotation dominated particles as the halo gets more mass? Would there be any way in which the ratio of those particles is increased? Also, if that mass slowly loses orbital velocity due to gravitational waves over time, and it eventually decays and collapses into a compact structure, would that structure have the angular momentum from the rotation dominated particles? Finally, could these halos have as much angular momentum as galaxies themselves?@LenardKasselmann

@vengaq I think the halo might be able to gain angular momentum from mergers with other (perhaps smaller halos). Not sure how large this effect is though.
The amount of energy that is lost due to gravitational waves in incredibly small. So this effect would only be noticable over extremely large timescales.

@vengaq I think the halo might actually have more angular momentum that the visible part of the galaxy. Simply because there is typically much more dark matter in a galaxy than baryons (i.e. visible matter). The reason why the visible part of the galaxy forms a disk and the halo doesn't is because the visible part can radiate energy through photons.

I see. Concerning the part about gravitational waves, even if we consider an extremely large timescale, when the particles of the halo would have lost their orbital energy, would they be clumped into a large compact object? Would it conserve the angular momentum from rotation dominated particles? @LenardKasselmann

@vengaq Yes. Over very long timescales the halo would likely collapse into a black hole. Note that even then angular momentum is conserved, because black holes can rotate.

@vengaq Btw, this is assuming that Dark Matter only interacts through gravity. For self-interacting dark matter, the halos collapse much earlier because the self-interactions transport heat outward (Gravothermal collapse).

And could there be some possibility in which, once it collapses, it does not end in a black hole? For instance, if we had halo of neutrinos around a galaxy that when collapsing would not be enough to turn into a black hole (but near that limit)? And in that case, would the halo have a higher angular momentum than most of the galaxy components not due to its mass content but rather due to the distance from the galactic center? @LenardKasselmann
